# Why is result of double arithmetic wrong?

Tags: c++, double

I have the following, in C++:

```
    double clsTime::dblSSM(INT16U uint16Hrs, INT16U uint16Mins, INT16U uint16Secs, INT16U uint16Hunds) {
        double dblHrsAsSecs  = (double)(uint16Hrs % 24) * 3600.0
              ,dblMinsAsSecs = (double)(uint16Mins % 60) * 60.0
              ,dblSecs       = (double)(uint16Secs % 60)
              ,dblHundreths  = (double)(uint16Hunds % 100) / 100.0
              ,dblSSM = dblHrsAsSecs + dblMinsAsSecs + dblSecs + dblHundreths;     
        return dblSSM;                      
    }
```

When calling this function with:

```
    dblResult = dblSSM(16, 56, 17, 13);
```

I can see in the debugger that the results of the intermediate variables are:

```
    dblHrsAsSecs  = 57600
    dblMinsAsSecs = 3360
    dblSecs       = 17
    dblHundreths  = 0.13
```

However when combined into dblSSM the result is:

```
    60977.1
```

What I want is: 60977.13 which is the correct answer, why is the .03 being dropped and how can I get it included?

To convert back to a string for checking:

```
    void clsTime::ssmToString(double dblSSM, char* pszBuffer, char szFormat[]) {
      INT8U uint8Hours, uint8Minutes, uint8Seconds, uint8Hundreths;
      double dblDummy;

      assert(pszBuffer != NULL);
      long lngSSM = (long)dblSSM;  
      uint8Hours = (INT8U)(lngSSM / ((long)mscuint16SecsInHour));
      uint8Minutes = (INT8U)((lngSSM % ((long)mscuint16SecsInHour)) /
                                               (long)mscuint16SecsInMinute);
      uint8Seconds = (INT8U)(lngSSM % (long)mscuint16SecsInMinute);
      int8Hundreths = (INT8U)(modf(dblSSM, &dblDummy) * 100.0);  
      sprintf(pszBuffer, szFormat, uint8Hours, uint8Minutes
                         , uint8Seconds, uint8Hundreths);
    }
```

szFormat is an optional parameter, the default passed in is:

```
    "%02.2u:%02.2u:%02.2u.%02.2u"
```

Comment: How do you watch that value? Did you try to print the value for example with more digits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/554134/8051589?

Comment: All the values are as displayed in the debugger, in watch window.  If I use the same value to convert back to a string I can see the result is also less the .03

Comment: Can the debugger show more digits or just the one you see? Try to get more digits displayed. If it's not possible use std::cout as in the answer given above.

Comment: Are you sure that `dblHundreths = 13` instead of `0.13` ?

Comment: @AndreKampling, as I said in my edit, the converted result back to a string shows the double is incorrect.

Comment: How do you convert to a string?

Comment: @AndreKampling, I'll edit my post and include the other function to convert back.

Comment: can you just print the results without debugger: `cout << dblSSM << all others too << endl`?

Comment: The answer below from GediminasLe is absolutely right. But back to your code which format string are you using? For example use "%.3f" to get more digits. Further you tagged your code as C++ but it's more C like except of that your using a class.

Comment: See edited post.

Comment: if you do this line: double d = 60977.13; what's the value that your debugger shows: 60977.13 or 60977.129999999997 ?

Comment: @JoãoAugusto, the debugger shows the correct result, I've event created an expression in the debugger which demonstrates the problem isn't the debugger.

Comment: If It shows 60977.13, then your debugger is rounding the value for display purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's not the result but your printing problem.
I have written this program:

```
#include <iostream> // cout
#include <iomanip> // fixed, setprecision

using namespace std;

double dblSSM(__uint16_t uint16Hrs, __uint16_t uint16Mins, __uint16_t uint16Secs, __uint16_t uint16Hunds) {
        double dblHrsAsSecs  = (double)(uint16Hrs % 24) * 3600.0
              ,dblMinsAsSecs = (double)(uint16Mins % 60) * 60.0
              ,dblSecs       = (double)(uint16Secs % 60)
              ,dblHundreths  = (double)(uint16Hunds % 100) / 100.0
              ,dblSSM = dblHrsAsSecs + dblMinsAsSecs + dblSecs + dblHundreths;     
        return dblSSM;                      
    }

int main () {

    cout << dblSSM(16, 56, 17, 13) << endl; // prints 60977.1
    cout << fixed << setprecision(8)/*output 8 in the decimal part */ << dblSSM(16, 56, 17, 13) << endl; // prints 60977.13000000

    return 0;
}
```

I think it works as it should.
If you want to print double you should use [setprecision](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/) and [fixed](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/fixed/).

EDIT:

```
cout << fixed << setprecision(12) << ( modf(dblSSM, &dblDummy) * 100.0);
```

Prints `12.999999999738` so `(__uint16_t)(modf(dblSSM, &dblDummy) * 100.0)` gives 12.
Hacky way to fix this is to use `round` function, but I suggest you not use doubles unless you really have.

Comment: The fact this answer has both [`bits/stdc++.h`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namesapce std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) makes it a horrible suggestion to any future reader.

Comment: Retracted DV. Still, the using directive makes me cringe.

Comment: But its not a display problem, why is dblSSM wrong?  How do you fix that?

Comment: @SPlatten function `clsTime::dblSSM` works correctly, where is problem in `clsTime::ssmToString`.

Comment: @GediminasLe, so what is the solution to getting dblSSM correct, I'm not interested in correcting the display, just the correct result.  dblSSM isn't correct because it returns a value without the .03

Comment: @SPlatten `dblSSM` is correct. `dblSSM(16, 56, 17, 13)` returns `60977.13`

Comment: Not with the compiler I'm using which is the now rather old Borland C++ 5.2, I don't have a choice on the compiler as its for an old embedded system.

Comment: @Splatten if you do: double d = 60977.13;
 unsigned int b = d * 100; what's the value of b on your debugger ?

Comment: @JoãoAugusto, same, I assigned value of dblTest = 60977.13 and the value actually displayed in the debugger is 60977.1, so is this an optimization?

Comment: @Splatten,  and what's the value of variable b (unsigned int b = dblTest * 100) ? If it's 6097713 then youre debugger is rounding values for display purposes.

Comment: @Splatten, that's because you declared b as a short, please use a uint32

Comment: Its been a long day :(

Comment: @JoãoAugusto, now the value of b is 6097712

Comment: @Splatten, so as you can see it's the debugger that is rounding for display purposes.